# Start a launcher on boot on all users

Tags: python, launcher, ubuntu-mate

i have created a desktop launcher and i was wondering how do i make the launcher start on boot on all users, the launcher initiates a script that creates a GUI and i need to GUI to be active on all users.

Comment: You can add your script to the Startup Applications.

Answer (score 1):

To make a launcher `.desktop` file autostart for all users, simply copy or link the `.desktop` file to `/etc/xdg/autostart`.
Copying seems  to bee a recommended practice since as you can see, all files under autostart directories are files.
More info about xdg autostart: https://specifications.freedesktop.org/autostart-spec/0.5/ar01s02.html

```
# sudo ln -s /usr/share/applications/mygui.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart/
sudo cp /usr/share/applications/mygui.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart/
# new files should be root:root, 0644
# sudo chmod 644 /etc/xdg/autostart/mygui.desktop
```